# Python, access data Dictionary in Dictionary

Tags: python

I have data like this :
[image]

As you can see : dictionary:list[{dictionary1},{dictionary2} ,... ]
How i can create loop to access all 'type' inside of every small dictionary ?
Thanks very much !

Comment: `[large_dictionary['type'] for large_dictionary in result_records.values()] + [small_dictionary['type'] for small_dictionary in large_dictionary.values() for large_dictionary in result_records.values()] `

Comment: I accidentally linked the wrong post and had to retract my close vote but I'm certain this question has been asked and answered many times on this site.

Comment: Please search this site for basic questions like this. It is likely to have been done before. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid down votes.

Comment: Thanks all very much, now i can access data i want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an answer after read instructions, 
i can access data with code like this :

```
 for item in result_records:
        getValues = result_records.get(item) # Return list of dictionary
        for subDict in getValues: # With every dictionary
            if(subDict['type'] == 'VIEW_ITEM'):
```

Thanks all very much for helping me !

Comment: You can also iterate through your dictionary like this: `for value in result_records.values(): ...` or if you need the key name `for key, value in result_records.items(): ...`

Comment: @machine yearning , thanks for reply. Now i want convert that "result_dictionaty" to csv. Which best way to do its ?

Comment: You'll probably have to do a google search for "convert dict to csv", could be really difficult but I bet someone's done it before!

Comment: @machine yearning , i want to insert data in my picture in question to MongoDB, but i only want insert "key" (53500....., A1D5....., .... ) and "id" with type = "VIEW_ITEM". Can you help me do that ?

Comment: No I cannot help you with that.